# Primary key and indexing in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

new to cassandra, still learning.

```
create table url (
  id_website int,
  url varchar,
  data varchar,
  primary key(url, id_website)
);
```

Hi I have a table of url for a website.

I don't want all the url being on the same node, that's why primary key is url first, so it will be the partition key.

most of the time I'm going to retrieve the data for a specific url, eg : "url = ? and id_website = ?"

However what about the performance when I want to retrieve a part/all the urls of a website:

```
select * from url where id_website = 1 allow filtering limit XX;
```

I think this query is going to be dispatched on all the nodes, then, table scanning for id_website=  1 until limit is reach then merged and sent back to my client.

But is this scanning going to use an index and be effective or read the values of the column id_website one by one and compare (ineffective so) ? I did set id_website part of the primary key so I expect it to be indexed, but I really don't know.

Do we have some tools on cassandra like the EXPLAIN of mysql to check if a query is using index or not.

Thanks.

--

## EDIT

> Create a second table with id_website as partition key (and
>   write/delete in batch)

I don't want to use this solution because I may have one or two website which are really huge and have millions of urls (and millions of others website with little of urls).

If I have a partition key on id_website, and that this two or three website stay on the same node it may cause storage problem or the node handling these websites maybe too much solicited while the other get nothing. I want to spread the data over all the nodes. That's why I insisted to partition on the url.

> You create a secondary index on id_website (which creates a table for
>   you)

What about this solution ? If I understand, each node would have a table indexing the rows it stores based on id_website (so not the rows of others nodes). So I can spread my urls across many nodes, I won't have one node handling a big indexing containing all the urls of a specific website.

Now when I use my query

```
select * from url where id_website = 1 allow filtering limit XX;
```

Each node receive the query, but they don't have to loop through the partition (url column) this time, they can directly lookup up in the index the urls belonging to id_website, and return the rows (or nothing). Right ?

The contra of this solution is everytime the request is done, it's going to hit each node, however, it should be fast thanks to the new index ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right way. Using allow filtering you're just asking cassandra to scan all nodes: very ineffective. `id_website` is indexed within each partition but since you are not telling Cassandra where to go he must hit all partitions (all nodes) even those who doesn't contain information for the selected `id_website` -- once Cassandra hit a partition knows how to look for this information and does not need to scan the whole partition to get data back.

To solve this problem in Cassandra you have to denormalize and in this situation you can do it in two possible ways:

1. Create a second table with id_website as partition key (and write/delete in batch)
2. You create a secondary index on id_website (which creates a table for you)

### **EDIT DUE TO QUESTION EDIT**

What you said is right: secondary indexes are handled as *"local indexes"* -- each node creates a local index table only for the data it owns. The following is a [good reading](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77) about secondary indexes (that you already understood)

Once you created the index you have to remove `ALLOW FILTERING` from the query.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: so you are telling me the id_website index won't be used on the nodes receiving the queries in this case. It will only be used in the case I do url=x and id_website=y right ?

Comment: I'm telling you that if you have 3000 partitions for "url" table and 1000  of these contains information for id_website=1 cassandra will query all 3000 partitions, 2000 of these will reply with empty value the 1000 remaining will not "scan" the partition since id_website is indexed within the partition.

Comment: ok I understand, but If there is a lot of urls (thousand of thousand) and small number of nodes (<16), each node is very likely to store urls for a website if they are equally distributed. In this case, every node would return something, hence it would not be a problem ?

Comment: Did not understand what you mean -- the number of urls is the number of partitions for this table -- in an equally distributed system with X nodes, each node will own about RF/X partitions (where a partition in this case is an url and RF is the replication factor) -- every node will be queried many times to get data for a specific id_website, returning nothing most of times. If you have a good number of id_website to monitor I'd think about changing the order of your primary key.

Comment: **If you have 3000 partitions for "url" table and 1000 of these contains information for id_website=1 cassandra will query all 3000 partitions.**

-> ok I think I understand, it's like in mysql, if you have a primary key (foo,bar) you can't use bar index without using foo before. 

-> So Cassandra scans all the partitions(urls) and use the id_website index for each url but it's ineffective because it have to scan partition before ? So yes we use an index but it's not effective.

Comment: thanks @Carlo I improved my question if you could take a look.

Comment: edited my answer to answer your new question - btw: you say you are new to cassandra | my congrats, you are very fast learner (I guess you already have some kind experience with distributed systems). Hope this helps

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a storage for my next software, I m looking in depth at cassandra first, then hbase (I want wide-column, scalable store). I like to know how the things works, and with the distributed wide-column store, I think it's very important to know how things are going to works in the background when you build/denormalize your schema. Fortunately there is a lots of blogs with technical details on Cassandra internals. And thanks for your link, it explains exactly what I had in mind about scaling and indexing.